# Can't run my c program and there are no errors

Tags: c, compilation

When I try to compile my code it does not run the command prompt but when I use the VSC it does run, my other c programs run but idk why this one doesn't, and it doesn't have any error when I compile, it just appears to finish the program but it doesn't show anything, pls help I want to know why so I can learn.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    const double mercury = 0.38;
    const double venus = 0.91;
    const double mars = 0.38;
    const double jupiter = 2.34;
    const double saturn = 1.06;
    const double uranus = 0.92;
    const double neptune = 1.19;
    double weight;
    int x;

    // Ask for the current weight on earth
    printf("\nEnter your current weight on earth: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &weight);
    // Show the options
    printf("\nThis are the planets in the solar system that you can go to: \n");
    printf("\n1.mercurty | 2.venus | 3.mars | 4.jupiter | 5.saturn | 6.uranus | 7.neptune \n");
    // Ask for the planet they want to go
    printf("\nEnter the number of the planet you would like to visit: \n");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    // calculate the weight
    if (x == 1)
    {
        weight *= mercury;
    }
    else if (x == 2)
    {
        weight *= venus;
    }
    else if (x == 3)
    {
        weight *= mars;
    }
    else if (x == 4)
    {
        weight *= jupiter;
    }
    else if (x == 5)
    {
        weight *= saturn;
    }
    else if (x == 6)
    {
        weight *= uranus;
    }
    else if (x == 7)
    {
        weight *= neptune;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("are you dumb or what? Select a number that appears in the options. \n");
    }
    // Print the weight
    printf("\nYou've selected the planet number: %d\n", x);
    printf("your weight will be: %f kg\n", weight);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When it "doesn't run" - what does it do instead?

Comment: It runs fine for me, in any environment. Unrelated: You should check the return value from your `scanf`s. If they fail, your program will have undefined behavior

Comment: Thank you very much for checking, what I mean by "it doesn't run" is that when I try to run the program in the command prompt it does nothing, when I put the gcc space.c does not run the program it sends me back where I have to put the gcc again